# Angular http.get error to retrieve backslash stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

I'm so frustrated with this.

I'm using Angular from CDN and I'm calling a $http.get request to **a PHP file that prints all the result set (mysql) in JSON format**, which is "well done".
But, I have stored some backslashes into the database as part of the value of a field. E.G:

```
{"Field 1":"user1"},{"Field 2":"some_data\2"}
```

That crashes the entire page and the data in the view is not being displayed. It's printed in the raw JSON file this way:

```
{"Field 2":"some_data�2"}
```

Currently I'm printing the resultant json "manually":

```
$outp = '{"Field 2":"'.$resultset['field_data'].'"}';
echo $outp;
```

I've tried everything I know: addslashes(), stripslashes(), htmlspecialchars(), json_encode()... Error is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token    in JSON at position 138742
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: are you returning it with `echo json_encode($response);` (from PHP)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that using $response as an associative array and also as a json string. In those cases, the PHP file prints nothing. Blank screen, no errors or warnings.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show how you're building that data. It may be parsing wrong in the PHP code.

Comment: Currently I'm printing the resultant json "manually":

$outp = '{ "Field 2" : " '.$resultset['field_data'].' " } ' ;
echo $outp;

Comment: Don't. Use `json_encode`, as it will properly escape any input to make a valid json string.

Comment: The problem is that when I get all my resultset in an array `echo json_encode($array)` prints nothing. I set the headers too: `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: You can check for [json_last_error()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [json_last_error_msg()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see if there's a reason why it's returning an empty string.

Comment: The way I'm printing the json is right. It works with all the previous fileds. If I limit my mysql query to just the previous record that one with the backslash everything is ok and the Angular view show all the data table...

Comment: Thanks @aynber, the error message is: 
`5: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`.
I imagine that is related to the � printed.
What can I do? utf8_encode()?

Comment: Yes, you can try that, or try `addslashes` either before the data is entered to the database or when you pull it out, since that slash isn't being used as an escape character.

Comment: Nothing... still the same, @aynber. This database was made a long time ago (not me) and there are some records with those bakcslashes. I just migrated that data to mysql. I suppose that I should replace them all. The bad thing is... they were stored in a .xls file as raw passwords, so I will need to change all those passwords on the social networks too...

Comment: Can you show how you're building the array before you use json_encode?

Comment: `$data[] = array(
  "ID"=>$rs["id"],
  "Client"=>$rs["client"],
  "URL"=>$rs["url"],
  "Admin"=>$rs["admin"],
  "Pass"=>$rs["pass"]
 );`

This pice of code is inside the "while" loop for the result set from mysql.

Comment: I'm guessing that the field you're attempting is the `pass` field, so try `"Pass"=>utf8_encode(addslashes($rs["pass"]))`

Comment: Nothing. If I do that, then it prints the pass just like it is: `"pass_with_a_\_on_it"`. So another error syntax error is shown. It assumes that I'm trying to esacape a "_" character.